# Foreach row display as column

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, foreach, html-table

I have a pretty standard database like:

```
id | name | last_name                | gender 
-----------------------------------------------
1  | John | Doe                      | Male
2  | Jane | Smith Dolores Clayborne  | Female
3  | Paul | Paulson                  | Male
```

and I want to display it in a table, but every row in the DB needs to be a column in HTML table:

```
id        | 1         | 2         | 3      
---------------------------------------------
name      | John      | Jane      | Paul
---------------------------------------------
last_name | Doe       | Smith     | Paulson
          |           | Dolores   |
          |           | Clayborne |
---------------------------------------------
gender    | Male      | Female    | Male
```

If I go with:

```
foreach($data as $row) {
echo "<tr><td>" . $row->id . "</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>" . $row->name . "</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>" . $row->last_name . "</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>" . $row->gender . "</td></tr>";
}
```

I get all the data in one long column. How do I break the column after every SQL row?

Note: `$data` is an array of objects that contain properties with the field values (you can probably figure that out from the example).

**EDIT:**

I found the solution, see my answer, it's simple and elegant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out, turns out it's a pretty simple solution with few cycles and pre-populating an array before writing rows and cells.

I tested it, works like a charm. ;) It might be useful for someone, so here it is:

```
foreach($records as $key => $row) {
       foreach($row as $field => $value) { 
           $recNew[$field][] = $value;
       }
}
//This creates a new array composed/transposed with the field names as keys and
//the "rowed" values as sub-arrays.

echo "<table>\n";

foreach ($recNew as $key => $values) // For every field name (id, name, last_name, gender)
{
    echo "<tr>\n"; // start the row
    echo "\t<td>" . $key . "</td>\n" ; // create a table cell with the field name
        foreach ($values as $cell) // for every sub-array iterate through all values
        {
           echo "\t<td>" . $cell . "</td>\n"; // write cells next to each other
        }
    echo "</tr>\n"; // end row

}

echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Answer has been updated for adjusted original post requirements as follows:

this is a wierd (or elegant) way to get what you want done and it will likely take tweaking to get it to look pretty, but it seems to work as you can see at the following url

http://www.bluevineconsulting.com/table_test.php

it has the php div method on top and does indeed show that the div's are different sizes as you had hoped would not happen. I have however come up with elegant/ugly solution that works with a table.

```
// i populated a fake object so i could test with it
$data = new stdClass();
$data->student1->id = "1";
$data->student1->name = "Test1";
$data->student1->last_name = "User1";
$data->student1->gender = "Male";
$data->student2->id = "2";
$data->student2->name = "Test";
$data->student2->last_name = "User<br>\nMaiden<br>\nOther\n";
$data->student2->gender = "Female";
$data->student3->id = "3";
$data->student3->name = "Test3";
$data->student3->last_name = "User3";
$data->student3->gender = "Male";
$data->student4->id = "4";
$data->student4->name = "Test4";
$data->student4->last_name = "User4";
$data->student4->gender = "Female";
$data->student5->id = "5";
$data->student5->name = "Test5";
$data->student5->last_name = "User5";
$data->student5->gender = "Female";
$data->student6->id = "6";
$data->student6->name = "Test6";
$data->student6->last_name = "User6";
$data->student6->gender = "Female";
$datacount = count($data);


foreach($data as $row) {
    $datacount++;
    if (empty($colcount)) {
        foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
            $colcount++;
            $keyname[$colcount] = $key;
        }
        echo "Columns = ".$colcount."<br>\n";
     }
}
echo "records = ".$datacount."<br>\n<br>\n";
echo ("<b>PHP Table method:</b><br>\n<br>\n");
echo ("<table border='1px' cellspacing='0'>\n");
foreach ($keyname as $key) {
    echo "    <tr style='vertical-align:top;'>\n";
    for ($d = 1; $d < $datacount; $d++) {
        $id = "student".$d;
        echo "        <td>".$data->$id->$key."</td>\n";
     }
    echo "    </tr>\n";
}
echo ("</table>\n");
```

i have to admit it is strange, but it keeps your tables with the correct heights .. the next more complicated part would be to set how many columns to show as this method makes it much more complicated to break after 5 columns like the div method I had earlier.

Comment: The second example could work as a workaround, but that doesn't solve the *EDITED situation*. I really need the data to be displayed in tables because I need every row to have the maximum height according to cell data, i.e. begin together.

Comment: actually .. that is mroe tricky ... matching row sizes with different div's ... gimme a second. :)

Comment: ok .. i have updated my answer with an ugly/elegant method that works as long as you don't want to break into a new table "row" at column 6 :) ... but in function it works like you want.

Comment: thank you for your effort, but I think this is more complex. I figured it out myself and answered it. I will select my answer as the definite one. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You should use "\n" at the end of every column you want in new line and "\t" for tabs:

```
foreach($data as $row) {

    echo "\t<tr><td>" . $row->id . "</td></tr>\n";
    echo "\t<tr><td>" . $row->name . "</td></tr>\n";
    echo "\t<tr><td>" . $row->last_name . "</td></tr>\n";
    echo "\t<tr><td>" . $row->gender . "</td></tr>\n";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a low-tech solution, but it may be sufficient.

```
$fmt="<tr><td>%s<br/>%s<br/>%s<br/>%s</td></tr>\n";
foreach($data as $row) {
  printf($fmt, $row->id, $row->name, $row->lastname, $row->gender);
}
```

Comment: Nope. Doesn't solve the problem. Still the same as my first try. Apparently break tags don't seem to work in td's...

Comment: That may be weirdness in your stylesheet, then.  A break should always be a break.  It would be interesting to see what my suggestion actually renders as for you.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to run that query within div's and some styling, so the code would be

```
<div align="center" style="float:left; width:100px; ">
<?    
$query = "select Something from your database";
$result = mysql_query($query);  
$results = mysql_num_rows($result);

//Now run the loop
for($i=0; $i<$results; $i++)
{   
echo'<div align="center" style="float:left; width:100px;">';
$records=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    foreach($records as $item)
    {
    echo'<div style="float:left;">'.$item.'</div>'; 
    }
echo '</div>';
}
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this working and we can avoid unwanted for loop.

foreach($data as $row) {

```
$idRow .= '<td>' . $row->id . '</td>';

$nameRow .= '<td>' . $row->name . '</td>';

$lastNmaeRow .= '<td>' . $row->last_name . '</td>';

$genderRow .=  '<td>' . $row->gender . '</td>';
```

}

```
 <tr><td>Id</td>'.$idRow.'</tr>
 <tr><td>Name</td>'.$nameRow.'</tr>
 <tr><td>Last Name</td>'.$lastNmaeRow.'</tr>
 <tr><td>Gender</td>'.$genderRow.'</tr>
```